# Problem in my script, not working in Google Chrome!

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I have a problem in my script and idk where maybe textContent is not working in Google Chrome, here is the code :

```
function afficher_temps() {
    var $ = unsafeWindow.$;
    var temps = document.getElementsByClassName('time hidden')[0].textContent;
    if(document.getElementById('temps')) {
        document.getElementById('temps').innerHTML = temps;
    }
    else {
        $('#banner').append('<br /><br /><dt id="temps">'+temps+'</dt>');
    }
    setTimeout(afficher_temps, 1000);
}
afficher_temps();
```

And the time that I want to extract is here :

```
<p class="time hidden" style="display: block; ">Time remaining:<br>1:10:07</p>
```

And also I want if the time is 00:00:05 will click a button :

```
<input class="Button1" type="button" style="padding: 10px" value="OK!">
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What isn't it doing? Please better explain the problem and considering mocking it up on jsfiddle.

Comment: Looks like JavaScript and not Java... fixed.

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName('time hidden')` looks very wrong (I think you can only look for *one* class name) and does definitely not work in IE. Why not use jQuery (or whatever library you use (I mean, you have `$('#banner')`)) for getting those elements?

Comment: Btw, I'm using this script in Greasemonkey, and now I just need : And also I want if the time is 00:00:05 will click a button :

<input class="Button1" type="button" style="padding: 10px" value="OK!">

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I often had problems using setTimeout. In your case I would suggest to use setTimeout in this way:

```
setTimeout("afficher_temps", 1000);
```

or

```
setTimeout(function(){
      afficher_temps();
}, 1000);
```

Maybe this could solve some problems. Bye